# how to contain header when I redirect in retrofit

Tags: android, redirect, retrofit2, oauth-2.0, okhttp

I tried to make oauth2 for android application. it has little bug.

My bug is It doesn't have header like Authorization when I redirect

MyCookieCode. It send Authorization when I was login. but It doesn't work when I redirect

```
public static Retrofit getLoginRetrofitOnAuthz() {
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ServerValue.AuthServerUrl).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    if (LoginRetrofitAuthz == null) {
        httpClientAuthz.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

                String str = etUsername.getText().toString() + ":" + etPassword.getText().toString();
                String Base64Str = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(str.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                System.out.println(Base64Str);
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization", Base64Str).build();

                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });   
        CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        httpClientAuthz.cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager));

        LoginRetrofitAuthz = builder.client(httpClientAuthz.build()).build();
    }
    return LoginRetrofitAuthz;
}
```

Server Result (Top-Login, Bottom, Redirect)
[image]

Do you know how to staying header on redirect ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in fact the sinner is OkHttp, but not Retrofit.
OkHttp removes all **authentication headers** on purpose:

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/7cf6363662c7793c7694c8da0641be0508e04241/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpEngine.java

```
// When redirecting across hosts, drop all authentication headers. This
// is potentially annoying to the application layer since they have no
// way to retain them.
if (!sameConnection(url)) {
  requestBuilder.removeHeader("Authorization");
}
```

Here is the discussion of this issue: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/977

You could use the OkHttp authenticator. It will get called if there is a 401 error returned. So you could use it to re-authenticate the request.

```
httpClient.authenticator(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
                return response.request().newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", "Token " + DataManager.getInstance().getPreferencesManager().getAuthToken())
                        .build();
            }
        });
```

However in my case server returned 403 Forbidden instead of 401. And I had to get 
`response.headers().get("Location");`

in-place and create and fire another network request:

`public Call<Response> getMoreBills(@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @Url String nextPage)`

Comment: in my case the server returned 200 after redirection. How can make another request if the code  is a success code ?