# okhttp redirect with Authorization header included?

Tags: java, okhttp

When performing a redirect, okhttp removes the Authorization header from the redirected request if the redirected request URL's schema, host or port differ from those in the original request's URL (see [RetryAndFolowUpInterceptor.kt](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/30780c879bd0d28b49f264fac2fe05da85aef3ad/okhttp/src/jvmMain/kotlin/okhttp3/internal/http/RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt#L303) and [Util.kt](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/30780c879bd0d28b49f264fac2fe05da85aef3ad/okhttp/src/jvmMain/kotlin/okhttp3/internal/-UtilJvm.kt#L130)).

I have a scenario where I need more control over this decision and - in certain cases - include the Authorization header in the redirected request when it would otherwise be removed.
I've looked at interceptors (and in fact I'm already using interceptors to implement automatic retry logic), but I haven't found a way to implement an alternate strategy for whether or not to include the Authorization header in a redirect.
Anyone have ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: to clarify the scenario a bit...  I have a library (https://github.com/IBM/java-sdk-core) that enables REST API request/response processing and all the okhttp-ness is hidden (more or less) in the library. Users of the library simply call functions which then carry out the REST API request processing under the covers using okhttp. I need to add to this library (in a generic manner) the ability to forward "safe" headers when a request is being redirected to a different host but yet still within a "trusted domain".  Ideally, there would be a hook point where I could define a callback function that decides whether or not to forward the safe headers for a particular redirected request.  I hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to contain header when I redirect in retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098623/how-to-contain-header-when-i-redirect-in-retrofit)

Comment: No, this is not related to retrofit, and I'm not really looking for how an "end user" of okhttp would be able to do this.  Instead, this scenario involves some function within a library that is used to enable REST API request/response processing and I would need to solve this via an interceptor or similar mechanism so that end users of my library are none the wiser :)