# How to customize retry/redirect logic in urllib3's Retry class

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I have a python-based library that serves as an enabling layer for processing REST API requests/responses (https://github.com/IBM/python-sdk-core).  Under the covers, it uses the requests and urllib3 libraries but hides these lower-level details from the user for the most part.
The library uses the urllib3 Retry class to enable automatic retries.  The Retry class supports the `remove_headers_on_redirect` parameter to specify the headers that should be removed from a redirected request.   Unfortunately, this is an all-or-nothing proposition and I'd like to have a bit more control over the removal/inclusion of these "safe" headers.  For example, I would want to include the Authorization header in a redirected request ONLY if the original request URL's host and the redirected URL's host are both in a "trusted domain".  So, the simple configuration of the `remove_headers_on_redirect` parameter is not quite sufficient as the decision needs to be conditional in my situation.

Is there any way for me to implement such a conditional inclusion of safe headers other than perhaps subclassing the urllib3 Retry class?  Ideally, the urllib3 Retry class would support some sort of callback hook to allow me to include my custom logic into the process of retrying and/or redirecting a request.

Note: I have a similar question about the Java okhttp library, here: [okhttp redirect with Authorization header included?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77483238/okhttp-redirect-with-authorization-header-included)

Comment: It's unspecific. You already know that feature is not supported. Why not implement a prototype and ask a specific question if you confront a problem? Your idea of implementing a custom Retry class is the right direction. See [the implementation](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/2.1.0/src/urllib3/poolmanager.py#L467) for the ```remove_headers_on_redirect``` attribute. You can adjust that attribute in the ```Retry.increment()``` method. (Modify the returned object of the ```super().increment(...)```.)